# PHPExcel conditional formatting when cell equals string

Tags: php, phpexcel

The following:

```
$objConditional1 = new PHPExcel_Style_Conditional();
$objConditional1->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_CONTAINSTEXT)
                ->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_CONTAINSTEXT)
                ->addCondition("Bla bla");
$objConditional1->getStyle()->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getEndColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_GREEN);   


$conditionalStyles = $sheet->getStyle('I2')->getConditionalStyles();
array_push($conditionalStyles, $objConditional1);               
$sheet->getStyle('I$2:I$10000')->setConditionalStyles($conditionalStyles);
```

Generates an excel document and says that the conditional formatting has issues and that it will remove it...

The correct result i'm looking for is when column equals "Bla bla" fill the box in green

Answer (score 12):

The change is instead of addCondition, you have to call setText... Which is hard to infer, but whatever... cool I got it to work.

```
$objConditional1 = new PHPExcel_Style_Conditional();
$objConditional1->setConditionType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::CONDITION_CONTAINSTEXT)
                ->setOperatorType(PHPExcel_Style_Conditional::OPERATOR_CONTAINSTEXT)
                ->setText("Bla bla");
$objConditional1->getStyle()->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getEndColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_GREEN);   


$conditionalStyles = $sheet->getStyle('I2')->getConditionalStyles();
array_push($conditionalStyles, $objConditional1);               
$sheet->getStyle('I$2:I$10000')->setConditionalStyles($conditionalStyles);
```

Comment: This also highlight to other matching sting any other alternative. Eg. 1/12 and 11/12 both get highlight